# Move a question to a new user

Tags: support, status-completed

A few weeks ago I asked [a question about the F-4 Phantom](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15419/what-is-the-smiley-face-sensor-at-the-stern-of-the-f-4-phantom) on behalf of my daughter. To encourage both her interest in aviation and also her interest in English, I have capitulated to her requests and opened a SE account for her:
[Happy Phantom](http://stackexchange.com/users/6544497/happy-phantom). I will be monitoring (actually, I'll be the one typing) her activity, at least for the first few years! She does not have access to (or knowledge of) the account password.

Could [her question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15419/what-is-the-smiley-face-sensor-at-the-stern-of-the-f-4-phantom) and related answers, rep, and comments be moved from my account to her account? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if it can be done or not, but you can flag that question and that will get a mod's attention.

Comment: @Farhan: Thank you, I've flagged the question with the appropriate details.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done, but I did want to say I think what you're doing is fantastic :).

Comment: This is just SO cool! Way to be an awesome father and encourage your daughter's curiosity. I hope I can do the same if/when I have kids. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not something we typically do, in fact it's not even something we allow a normal moderator to do because it's essentially rewriting history and moving reputation around.

I'll reassign the question, but with a couple of warnings:

1. This is the *one* reassignment you get. If you post under the wrong account in the future, you'll just have to live with it, or you can delete the post and re-post under the right account.
2. Do not use one account to upvote the other. That's essentially [sockpuppeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)), and if a moderator notices, then both accounts are likely to be suspended, and the votes will be reversed.

There you go. Have fun.

Comment: Thank you Bret! It means a lot to her, and I will be sure to explain also _why_ we do not upvote one another. Have a terrific week!